# A modern MDZS fanfic where Wei Wuxian, a flutist (music student) comes to coparent Wen Yuan after the child was left in his apartment

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction

**PLOT:**

It is set in USA. Wei Wuxian is an international student from China. He is a music student and flutist for his choir where Lan Wangji is a main pianist. They also share a course.

It literally starts when Wei Wuxian wakes after a night of party to find there's a baby (4-5 ish) in his apartment. He also spots a bag with all basic baby essentials left in his apartment and a note explaining he (the dad) is leaving the kid (Wen Yuan) here for sometime. The baby was very calm indicating it was a common occurence. He phones around and sometime later learns from his sister that the kid's dad is a good for nothing person. In the meantime he decides, he is going to look after the kid.

It's a bit of a slice of life kind fanfic. We see Wei Wuxian buying toys and  things needed for a kid. For the first day, he even takes him to college class and the whole class is enamoured by the kid. Somehow, Lan Wangji also ends up taking care of the kid.

Also they take the kid to Wei Wuxians sister's home. In this setting, her husband is a sirgeon.

---

**Site:** Archive of Our Own (AO3)

**Category** Fanfiction

- Of MDZS/The Untamed/Mo Dao Zhu Shi (all are same)
- MDZS is a Chinese webnovel

**Tags:** Modern universe, No power, Wei Wuxian/Lan Wangji

**Time** 2018-2021

**Title and Author:** Don't Know

---

I had only read it halfway so can't describe the whole thing. But this was a fairly unique concept for a fanfic.

Even after filtering the tags, I am left with hundreds (not exaggerating)of fanfic to sort through (this novel has a pretty big fanfic base).

Has anyone else heard about this fanfic?